# Find largest number divided by which each element of vector is integer

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is my first question on math.stackexchange, and as you will notice, I am not a mathematician at all, and this may be a very simple question. Apologies.

I also don't know if I used the right terms when asking the title, so here an example of what I am looking for (the c() is from R, it concatenates to a vector, in this case of numerics or integers)

I am looking for a *generalized way* to find the largest number divided by which each element of a vector would result in an integer.

```
c(1, 3, 5) # expected result = 1
c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6) # expected result = 0.2 
c(0.3, 0.5, 0.7) # expected result = ??? this is where I am stuck
```

Comment: Divide by $0.1$.

Comment: If you convert the numbers into fractions, it can easier be described what to do exactly in general. Are you familiar with $\gcd$ and $lcm$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok yes, this works in this example, thanks, but is there a general way?

Comment: @Peter I see the reasoning behind it, but this is not ideal because in the end I want to use it for R and it doesn't really use fractions. Maybe I should indeed ask this in stackoverflow instead, but I though it was more a mathematical problem

Comment: @Peter no, I am not, unfortunately :(

Comment: OK, I try to formulate a solution avoiding that. For all numbers, count the number of digits after the decimal point. Assume $m$ is the maximum that occurs. Dividing by $10^{-m}$ gives integers. To find the best number you have to divide by the largest common divisor of the resulting numbers. For example : $3,6,9$ have $3$ as the largest common divisor. Multiply $10^{-m}$ with this number to get the final result. To get the number in the second step, you can for example determine the divisors of the first integer and check them. If zeros occur, you can ignore them.

Comment: I hope this was helpful.

Comment: It absolutely is. I will check and try to implement it, but I am sure you should already post this as an answer!!!

Comment: @Peter Merajul has posted the very exact solution, but like 20 minutes later - I would be happily accept your answer if you would post it. Let me know

Comment: @Tjebo I have enough points. It is OK, if you accept the answer below.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks again to both of you, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about linear algebra that much too, but I think I can answer this question.

You have a vector $V$. Let's denote $V[i]$ as i'th element of $V$ and $L$ as the length of $V$. Now, you want to find a number let's say $n$. Now if you divide each $V[i]$ with n every element of $V$ would become an integer. Now, the simplest way that I can think of would be taking $n = 10^{-d}$ where you can set $d$ by examining $V$. Now let's denote a function $f(x)$ which returns the number of digits $n$ has after the decimal point. Some examples would be, $f(1.512) = 3$ because there are 3 digits after the decimal point in $1.512$ . Now we have to find the maximum value of $f(V[i])$ for $i \in [1, L] $. Now $d$ has to be equal to that maximum value.

Let's take the last example that you mentioned in your question. $V(0.3, 0.5, 0.7)$.

$f(0.3) = 1$
$f(0.5) = 1$
$f(0.7) = 1$

So, the maximum value of those three values is $1$. So $d = 1$ and $n = 10^{-1}$. Now we have to each element of $V$ by $n$. After that we get $V' = (3, 5, 7)$.

Now you wanted the largest $n$. So, we got to take another step. We have to multiply $n$ by the $gcd(V')$. where $gcd$ means $Greatest\ Common\ Divsior$ and $gcd(V')$ means the $gcd$ of all the elements of $V'$. Now you should have the greatest $n$ by which if the elements of $V$ are divided they would result in an integer.

Comment: That's a very nice solution, thanks for your help. Peter had posted the exact same solution as a comment rouhgly 20 minutes before you (not much time, you must have had the same idea :) However, if Peter decides to post this as an answer, I would accept this.

Comment: Yeah, I saw Peter's solution after I finished writing my one. He and I had the exact idea I think. But I think he was faster. So, I also think you should accept his one. And you got your answer that's all that matters.